# How can I set boolean pgfkeys?

Tags: macros, pgfkeys, ifthenelse

I am making a command called `seal` that needs a boolean `key=value` option. Since I don't know how to do this, I am using `key=yes` and `key=no` for defining my `pgfkeys` as follows.

```
\pgfkeys{
/seal/.is family, /seal,
% "seal" options
invert/.estore in = \sealInvert,
other/.estore in = \sealOther,}
```

An then, I define `\seal` roughly as follows:

```
\newcommand{\seal}[2][]{%
\pgfkeys{/seal,invert=no,other=value,#1}%
    %
    % IF invert=no
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\storeInvert}{no}}{%
        Code...}{%
    % ELSEIF invert=yes
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\storeInvert}{yes}}{%
        Code...}{%
    % ELSE
    \PackageWarning{seal}{Unknown option invert=\storeInvert.}}}%
}
```

I'd like to know how to redefine this in order to have a code like this:

```
\newcommand{\seal}[2][]{%
    \pgfkeys{/seal,invert=false,other=value,#1}%
    %
    % IF invert=false
    \ifthenelse{\NOT\storeInvert}{%
        Code...}{%
    % ELSE (invert=true)
        Code...}%
}
```

In case other value is passed (e.g. `invert=blah`), I'd like `\seal` to return a message like:

```
Unknown option `invert=blah`: `blah` is not boolean.
```

This last may not be necessary, though. It would depend on what is printed when a non boolean value is passed into a boolean key.

Thanks in advance for any help.

PS: The packages I am using/requiring are `graphicx`, `tikz` `pgfkeys`, and `ifthen`.

Comment: You are looking for ‘.is choice’, I think.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check info about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `.is choice` key. Of course, I do not know what you want to do if any of the Booleans is true or false, so I just replaced the code by some message and typeset. You need to replace the right-hand sides `...` of

```
invert/true/.code=...
```

by your own codes. The following illustrates how this works. The code also contains some more explanations in the comments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\pgfkeys{/seal/.is family, /seal/.cd, %<-added /.cd 
invert/.is choice,
invert/.default=false,
invert/true/.code={\message{Set /seal/invert to true.^^J}Set /seal/invert to true.}, %<-replace by your own
invert/false/.code={\message{Set /seal/invert to false.^^J}Set /seal/invert to false.}, %<-replace by your own
other/.is choice,
other/.default=false,
other/true/.code={\message{Set /seal/other to true.^^J}Set /seal/other to true.}, %<-replace by your own
other/false/.code={\message{Set /seal/other to false.^^J}Set /seal/other to false.}, %<-replace by your own
}
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/seal/invert=true}\par
\pgfkeys{/seal/other=false}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In view of your comment, here is a version using the `/.is if` key. Unlike the `/.is choice` key, this is a Boolean, i.e. only `true` and `false` are allowed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\newif\ifsealinvert
\newif\ifsealother
\pgfkeys{/seal/.is family, /seal/.cd, %<-added /.cd 
invert/.is if=sealinvert,
other/.is if=sealother,
}
\newcommand{\seal}[2][]{%
\pgfkeys{/seal,invert=false,other=true,#1}%
    %
    % IF invert=no
    \ifsealinvert
     \message{seal invert is true.^^J}%
     seal invert is true.
    \else 
       \message{seal invert is false.^^J}%
     seal invert is false.
    \fi 
    \ifsealother
     \message{seal other is true.^^J}%
     seal other is true.
    \else 
       \message{seal other is false.^^J}%
     seal other is false.
    \fi 
}
\begin{document}
\seal{}\par
\seal[invert=true]{}\par
\seal[other=false]{}\par
\seal[invert=true,other=false]{}\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

And you can mix these e.g. as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\newif\ifsealinvert
\newif\ifsealother
\pgfkeys{/seal/.is family, /seal/.cd, %<-added /.cd 
invert/.is choice,
invert/yes/.code=\sealinverttrue,
invert/no/.code=\sealinvertfalse,
other/.is if=sealother,
}
\newcommand{\seal}[2][]{%
\pgfkeys{/seal,invert=no,other=true,#1}%
    %
     \ifsealinvert
     \message{seal invert is yes.^^J}%
     seal invert is yes.
    \else 
       \message{seal invert is no.^^J}%
     seal invert is no.
    \fi 
    \ifsealother
     \message{seal other is true.^^J}%
     seal other is true.
    \else 
       \message{seal other is false.^^J}%
     seal other is false.
    \fi 
}
\begin{document}
\seal{}\par
\seal[invert=yes]{}\par
\seal[other=false]{}\par
\seal[invert=yes,other=false]{}\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks again! I'll study your answer.

Comment: @LuisBartolo For the case of an unknown key look at section **87.3.6 Keys That Are Unknown** of pgfmanual v3.1.4.

Comment: Thanks, I won't need the `.unknown` for this command. I'd rather like to store the boolean value of `invert` in a variable `\invertVar`, so that I can use it in `ifthenelse` statements. For example, `\ifthenelse{\invertVar}{Code if invert=true...}{Code if invert=false...}`. I'm not sure how to do it with your first answer, but it's still helpful.

Comment: @LuisBartolo You can define e.g. `invert/true/.code={\def\invertVar{true}}` but to me this looks unnecessarily complicated. You may use the `/.is if` key for that, see the example on top of p. 974 of pgfmanual v3.1.4.

Comment: this what says in the manual is better than I thought. It will make unnecessary for me to use the `ifthenelse` package. Thanks again!

Comment: @LuisBartolo Yes, you won't need the `ifthenelse` package. I added an example for the `/.is if` key. Of course, you can mix these by introducing the `\newif`s in the first example and doing something like `invert/yes/.code={\sealinverttrue}`.

Comment: @user194703   Could you eventually show your example with the usage of `/.is if` ?