# pgfkeys: Different output depending on a keyword

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, pgfkeys, key-value

I need an output like

`\cmd` --> "S0" (output)

`\cmd[]` --> "S0" (output)

`\cmd[map]` ----> "S1 S2 S3" (output)

`\cmd[map=true]` ----> "S1 S2 S3" (output)

`\cmd[map=false]` ----> "S0"  (output)

I looked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506426/how-can-i-set-boolean-pgfkeys?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114012/simple-example-of-pgfkeys). How can I get a command *with pgfkey* for that?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
    /map/.is family, 
    /map/.cd, %<-added /.cd 
     map/.is choice,
     map/.default=false,
     map/true/.code={S1 S2 S3}, 
     map/false/.code={S0}, 
}
\newcommand{\cmd}[1][]{%
%\tikzset{#1}%
\pgfkeys{map=true}
}

\begin{document}
Test:

\cmd[map]

\cmd[]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Comments in the code...

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys} %no need to full-load tikz
\pgfkeys{%/tikz/.cd, you want your top-family, no?
     % /map/.is family,
     % /map/.cd, %<-added .cd why?
     /map/.is choice,
     % /map/.default=false, % not useful in choices, you have to call one of them anyway
     /map/true/.code={S1 S2 S3},
     /map/false/.code={S0},
}
\newcommand{\cmd}[1][false]{%
\pgfkeys{/map=#1}
}

\begin{document}
Test:

\cmd[true]

\cmd % if you use \cmd[] you ends with /map= which is not a choice
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that `true` and `false` are fully customizable here --- you can call them whatever you want, they're just names.

Anyway, I would rather separate the key management and the code. So I will

1. define a top family for my application
2. add a specific function to set keys in this family
3. use the keys to switch/set things

Like this:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\newif\ifdomap\domapfalse
\pgfkeys{
     /cis/.is family, /cis/.cd,
     map/.is choice,
     map/true/.code={\domaptrue},
     map/false/.code={\domapfalse},
}
\newcommand{\cisset}[1]{\pgfkeys{/cis/.cd, #1}}

\newcommand{\cmd}[1][]{%
    \begingroup % change the keys locally
    \cisset{#1}%
    \ifdomap
        S1 S2 S3
    \else
        S0
    \fi
    \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

Test:
\par No map: \cmd
\par Map (locally): \cmd[map=true]
\par No map: \cmd
\par Set globally to true \cisset{map=true}
\par Map: \cmd
\par No map (locally):  \cmd[map=false]
\par Set globally to false \cisset{map=false}
\par No map: \cmd

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is a bit low level, you can use `xifthen` package if you are addressing just LaTeX.

If you want a simple  `map` key, you just do not use the `is choice` handler:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\newif\ifdomap
\pgfkeys{
     /cis/.is family, /cis/.cd,
     map/.code={\domaptrue},
     no map/.code={\domapfalse},
     no map % set the default
}
\newcommand{\cisset}[1]{\pgfkeys{/cis/.cd, #1}}

\newcommand{\cmd}[1][]{%
    \begingroup % change the keys locally
    \cisset{#1}%
    \ifdomap
        S1 S2 S3
    \else
        S0
    \fi
    \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

Test:
\par No map: \cmd
\par Map (locally): \cmd[map]
\par No map: \cmd
\par Set globally to true \cisset{map}
\par Map: \cmd
\par No map (locally):  \cmd[no map]
\par Set globally to false \cisset{no map}
\par No map: \cmd

\end{document}
```

[image]

And finally, this allows to have both the `map` switch and a `map=...` switch, similar to lot of options in Ti*k*Z. This uses an auxiliary key and a style with an (optional, thanks to the `.default`) argument.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\newif\ifdomap
\pgfkeys{
     /cis/.is family, /cis/.cd,
     domap/.is choice,
     domap/false/.code={\domapfalse},
     domap/true/.code={\domaptrue},
     map/.style={domap=#1},
     map/.default=true, % for this key
     domap=false, % global default
}
\newcommand{\cisset}[1]{\pgfkeys{/cis/.cd, #1}}

\newcommand{\cmd}[1][]{%
    \begingroup % change the keys locally
    \cisset{#1}%
    \ifdomap
        S1 S2 S3
    \else
        S0
    \fi
    \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

Test:
\par No map: \cmd
\par Map (locally): \cmd[map]
\par Map (locally): \cmd[map=true]
\par No map (locally, forced): \cmd[map=false]
\par No map (default): \cmd
\par Set globally to true \cisset{map} % or \cisset{map=true}
\par Map: \cmd
\par No map (locally):  \cmd[map=false]
\par Set globally to false \cisset{map=false}
\par No map: \cmd

\end{document}
```

[image]

A very nice answer is also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114017/38080

Comment: Ahh, good. Is it possible to create that like `\cmd[map]`  or `\cmd[]` = `\cmd[map=false]`?    Because, there should come lots of other parameters / keys, so "`\cmd[true]`" is not a good syntax.

Comment: @cis like this? This is basically how I use the keys in `circuitikz`. There is even a special key handler to automatically associate to an if, but  I find this easier to read.

Comment: I have two problems here: 

- \cmd[map] alone seems not to work.

- But fundamentally I wonder why this seems not to be possible with "plain pgfkeys syntax"

Comment: Because: It is clear that this is an abstract, simplified MWE from me. I don't just want to write "S1 S2 S3". I can hardly list the 17 lines that are hidden behind "S2" in the "MWE".
That I basically need numerous other keys - that means: If this is only possible in such a complicated way, I cannot use it.
But it has to be easier. Mmhhh ...

I should basically understand this pgfkey syntax. Then I could do the rest alone.
But, as I said, if this is only possible with all possible other "plain TeX" methods, then I can not deduce from it.